# GoogleMap.animateCamera not working on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps

How do I change the camera focus inside a background thread?
The zoom works fine in the thread, but changing the coordinates doesn't.
Also changing the coordinates works if not used in the thread, but I intend on using delays so It needs to be in there.

```
@Override
        public void run() {

            if (points.size() > 0){
                Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(points)
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED));
                System.out.println(points.get(0).toString());
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(points.get(0)));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you may not be running this in a main UI thread

Change

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(points.get(0)));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
```

to

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(points.get(0)));
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
                     }
                    });
```

Comment: Forgot to mention Im using delays so I cant run in the Ui thread

Comment: Using delays does not stop using runOnUIThread !  If you have to update any UI from other threads you need to use this method/ handlers or someother technique

Answer (score 0):

`AnimateCamera` API is implemented in another thread already for you. So you must call it in UI thread. [Details about API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-methods)