# android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView that was originally added here

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error on this line of code and cannot figure out the root cause

```
closedialog.show();
```

I have tried putting a try/catch around it but the error still persists.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try{

                                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    alert.setTitle("Message");
                                    alert.setMessage(alertMessage);
                                    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.recharge_icon);
                                    //alert.show();
                                    final AlertDialog closedialog= alert.create();
                                    closedialog.show();
                                    final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
                                    timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            closedialog.dismiss(); 
                                            timer2.cancel(); //this will cancel the timer of the system
                                        }
                                    }, 8000); // the timer will count 5 seconds....

                                }catch(Exception ex){
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                }   
                           });
                        }
                    };
                    new Thread(runnable).start();
                    return
```

;

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: dont do it in runnable, you are losing a connection to activity

Comment: use runonuithread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252444/googlemap-animatecamera-not-working-on-background-thread/37252538#37252538

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added/37118300#37118300

Comment: Didnt work @Stallion